# Pass argument to QWidget.mousePressEvent

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am overriding the QWidget.mousePressEvent like this:

```
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
widget.mousePressEvent = my_function

def my_function(QMouseEvent):
    print('Mouse Pressed')
```

But my question is, how do I now pass it a variable? I need something like this:

```
for index in range(10):
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widget.mousePressEvent = my_function(index)

def my_function(QMouseEvent, index):
    print(index)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `functools.partial`

```py
from functools import partial

def my_function(index, QMouseEvent):
    print(index)

for index in range(10):
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widget.mousePressEvent = partial(my_function, index)
```

Or use lambda

```py
    widget.mousePressEvent = lambda: event, index=index: my_function(index, event)
```

Notice that optional lambda argument used for capturing index by value.